# What is this new grass path block?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

What is this grass path block? I'm playing on the Xbox One Edition, and the update just came out today. I can't find anything on the wiki for this block.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This grass path block is a [Grass Path block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Grass_Path).

It is mentioned as being added in the [latest update post](http://mojang.com/2016/10/console-update-banners-blocks-beets-bears/) (see last paragraph).

*(on PC)* It generates naturally in Savanna villages, and can be made from grass blocks by "using" a shovel on them.

Comment: Well, the first part of the answer states that the grass path block is a Grass Path Block, doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Alex One might argue that asking question that contains the answer doesn't make much sense :-) While it is of course a play of words, I mean that "that block you call 'grass path' is officially called exactly that and here you go a link to the wiki article for it".

Comment: @Alex It might make more sense if you notice that "Grass Path" is a link (which I did not at first).